# How to return Task<IEnumerable<T>>?

Tags: c#, task, ienumerable

I have a public Method

```
public Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> GetMyClassObjects()
{
        return ??myresult??;
}
```

and how can I return the correct result?

Comment: You might be looking for how to return an enumerable of `MyClass` asynchronously but without more context it is hard to say for sure.

Comment: Post your logic which you are trying to implement in `GetMyClassObjects` and we can give some hints

Comment: also, could you share your .Net and C# version?

Answer (score 12):

If you have a regular IEnumerable, so not as a result of another task method.

You can return it like this.

```
return Task.FromResult(Enumerable.Empty<MyClass>());
```

or

```
return Task.FromResult(myResult);
```

Comment: It is no need return type to be a result of an async operation. It is enough to call any kind of awaitable method to be able to return not `Task`, but `IEnumerable` in this case